# Getting "invalid literal for int() with base 10" error for DecimalField

Tags: django

I'm trying to do a sumproduct query in django:

```
merchandise_value = Product.objects.all()\
    .aggregate(merch_value=Sum(F('qty_ordered')*F('msrp')))
```

`'msrp'` is a `DecimalField` field (with 2 `decimal_places`). `'qty_ordered'` is an `IntegerField`. Even if I do crazy things like `int(float(F('msrp')))` or `int(float(str(F('msrp'))))` I still get:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'F(msrp)'
```

Other similar questions propose a similar solution to what I have used. What have I screwed up? And probably more importantly, why is there a call to `int()` somehow integrated into that line? I haven't explicitly called `int()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I suppose in this case you should call `output_field=FloatField()` explicitly to `Sum` to get needed output data type because database operations may not decide between this two data types:

```
from django.db.models import F, FloatField, Sum
...
merchandise_value = Product.objects.all()\
    .aggregate(merch_value=Sum(F('qty_ordered')*F('msrp'),output_field=FloatField()))
```

Take a look at this [Django examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet)

Comment: Ah, thanks; it's mentioned here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations